# Display Image Stream from S3 in Browser

Tags: node.js, image, amazon-s3, hapi.js

I am reading an image from S3 and sending it as Stream from my Node/Hapi Server like so
```

```
  return h.response(S3.getObject(params).createReadStream();).encoding(null);
```

```
This works fine if I dont have to pass any headers to my node server and I put the api endpoint directly inside the 
But I also need to pass some custome headers and I an using Axios to download the same stream , once the binary is downloaded, I am trying to put it in  as

`` <img src=`data:image/png;base64,${image}` /> ``

But this does not seem to work.
Any ideas how I can achieve this, I cannot expose the S3 URL directly/publicly.

Answer (score 1):

If Someone stumbles across this question, the problem was with the Axios library.
The answer can be found here...

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.request({
   url: 'http://XXXXXXXXX/path/myimage.jpeg',
   responseType: 'blob',
})
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
    .then(src => this.setState({ src }))  // OR imageEl.setAttribute("src", src);
    .catch(onFail);
```

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/448

The responseType:blob must be specified so that axios returns a blob object which can then be set to the image source.

Comment: Please include the actual solution within the answer, and [not just a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/211183).